# How to tell what zone map (blocks) read by amazon redshift query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to tell if the zone map is used by a specific query.
Is there a way to list block query read

My query is taking more time than expected, I just want to make the sure the query is using zone map to filter out blocks.

Comment: I don't think you can obtain this low-level information for a query. The first step should be to use the `EXPLAIN` plan and find the part of the plan that is taking the most time. Zone maps take advantage of the `SORTKEY`, so if your query has a `WHERE` clause that matches the `SORTKEY`, it will be relatively efficient. Feel free to add your query and `EXPLAIN` plan to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table [`stl_scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_SCAN.html) contains this information.

- `is_rrscan` indicates if the scan used range restriction (zone maps).
- `rows_pre_user_filter` is the row count *before* zone map restrictions
- `rows_pre_filter` is the row count *after* zone map restrictions
- `rows` is the row count after all predicates were evaluated

```sql
SELECT query, segment 
     , tbl, perm_table_name
     , is_rrscan
     , SUM( rows_pre_user_filter ) rows_on_table
     , SUM( rows_pre_filter )      rows_scanned
     , SUM( rows )                 rows_returned
FROM stl_scan
WHERE query = 999999
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5
```